# Promises.all on single promise returns object not array - cannot use forEach on returned data without checking for Array

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

How to handle single and multiple promises in the same Promise.all() code?  upload() is an async function

e.g.

```
let promises = [];
promises.push( upload('file1.txt','file1.txt') );
promises.push( upload('file2.txt','file2.txt') );

Promise.all(promises).then( data => {
  // this forEach is fine as 'data' is an array 
  data.forEach( function(f) { 
    console.log("Uploaded:", f.name); }
  );
}).catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

but if I try to promise with only one file then the forEach will fail.

```
let promises = [];
promises.push( upload('file1.txt','file1.txt') );

Promise.all(promises).then( data => {
  // this forEach FAILS as data is an object
  data.forEach( function(f) { 
    console.log("Uploaded:", f.name); }
  );
}).catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

Comment: No, that should not happen. What promise library are you using? Anything that is built on jQuery deferreds, which have this weird behavior?

Comment: As Bergi says, this will not happen with any standards-compliant implementation of `Promise.all()`.  So, either there's something else confusing you in your real code or you need to switch to a standards-compliant `Promise.all()` implementation that will not do this or you have to check if the result is an array (when using a non-standard `Promise.all()` that behaves in this weird way).  The standard `Promise.all()` will always resolve with an array.  The array may have 0, 1 or more items in it depending upon what you passed `Promise.all()`.

Comment: You are both correct - this code doesn't fail as I describe.  There was a moment in the development of the code - upload() is a wrapper for an S3.upload() - when I was seeing the error but to be honest it was undoubtedly my experimentation with various return/chain approaches.  Still at least this makes it clear that an array is always returned and if you don't get one then check your code.  This was just NodeJS + AWS-SDK - nothing fancy. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise returned by `Promise.all` always resolves to an array, even if only one promise is provided as an input, so I guess the reason your code is failing lies in the nature of the returned `data` structure.

```js
let promises = [];
promises.push( upload('file1.txt','file1.txt') );

Promise.all(promises).then( data => {
  data.forEach( function(f) { 
    console.log("Uploaded:", f.name); }
  );
}).catch(error => { 
  console.error(error.message);
});

async function upload(fileName) {
   return { name: 'filename.example' };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check that 'data' is of type Array before using (annoyingly)

```
if ( Array.isArray(data) ) {
  data.forEach( function(f) { 
    console.log("Uploaded:", f.name); }
  );
}
else {
  console.log("Uploaded:", data.name); 
}
```

Comment: Its annoying because it could return an array with one (or even zero for that matter) element and then the resolving code is much cleaner IMHO (I'm not advocating ignoring all type checks - that's why typescript exists)

Comment: The native `Promise.all` *does* precisely that.